# Проблема с быстрой сортировкой

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Доброго времени суток. Я написал функцию быстрой сортировки массива в порядке убывания в с++, но она почему-то сортирует массив не полностью, проблема наверняка в алгоритме, но я так и не смог понять, что не так. Вот код:

```
void quick_sort(int* a, int n){
  if(n <= 1) return; // если массив из одного элемента или меньше, то не сортируем
  int c = n/2;
  int l = 0;
  int r = n-1;
  int piv = a[c];

  while(l < r){
    while(a[l] > piv) l++;
    while(a[r] < piv) r--;
    if(l < r){
      int tmp = a[l];
      a[l++] = a[r];
      a[r--] = tmp;
    }
  }
  quick_sort(a, c);
  quick_sort(a+c, n-c);
}
```

Вот пример его работы:

```
massiv:
8 8 1 10 2 9 2 6 2 9 
quick sort:
10 9 9 2 1 8 8 6 2 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не так делите, надо рекурсивно вызывать не посредине, а там, где сошлись `l` и `r`.

```
void quick_sort(int* a, int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return; // если массив из одного элемента или меньше, то не сортируем
    int piv = a[n/2];
    int l = 0;
    int r = n-1;
    do
    {
        while(a[l] > piv) l++;
        while(a[r] < piv) r--;
        if (l <= r){
            int tmp = a[l];
            a[l++] = a[r];
            a[r--] = tmp;
        }
    } while(l <= r);

    if (r > 0)   quick_sort(a,r+1);
    if (l < n-1) quick_sort(a+l,n-l);
}
```

Comment: А почему во внутреннем if должно быть меньше либо равно? Ведь если лево и право равны, то это тот же самый элемент, и заменять его смысла нет? Но если сделать это условие строго меньше, то сортировка левой части массива уходит в бесконечную рекурсию для двух элементов, не пойму, как это связано

Comment: @Shadasviar когда строго не рекурсия бесконечная а внешний цикл `while`, так как в случае, когда `l == r` при строгом меньше `l` и `r` никогда не меняются вот и выходит бесконечный цикл, а то что один и тот же элемент меняет сам себя это не страшн ( хотя возможно можно и без этого побочного эффекта как то обойтись), кстати, посмотрите также мою версию реализации в новом ответе.

Answer (score 1):

предложу свой вариант реализации...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void qsort(int* arr, int l, int r)
{
    if (l >= r)
        return;

    int pivot = arr[l + ((r - l) >> 1)];
    int i = l, j = r;

    for (; l <= r; )
    {
        for (; arr[l] > pivot; ++l);
        for (; arr[r] < pivot; --r);

        if (l <= r)
        {
            std::swap(arr[l++], arr[r--]);
        }
    }

    qsort(arr, i, l - 1);   
    qsort(arr, l, j);
}

void qsort(int* arr, int size)
{
    qsort(arr, 0, size - 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr[] = { 4, 10, -1, 2, 5, 13, 6, 0, 3 };
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    qsort(arr, size);
    for (int a : arr)
    {
        std::cout << a << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```